# In Java, I can't add code after the return statement in a method

Tags: java

I'm new at Java, I'm learning about methods with a return statement.
My IDE says:

> This method must return a result of type boolean

However my method returns only boolean values. How to fix that ?

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] aargs) {
    debug(4, 5);
}

public static boolean debug(int a, int b) {
    if(a+b == 12) {
        return true;
    }else if(a+b == 18){
        return false;
    }
    a = 8;
}
```

}

Comment: Be aware that assigning a value to a is pointless here, even if the statement was executed.

Comment: The compiler doesn’t know if either of your conditions will be true so it’s saying you need to return a Boolean that  will always be hit in the case that neither of the first two conditions are true. So, you need either a return true or return false after a = 8.

Answer (score 3):

It is the design pattern of java. We cannot write any code after return statement. If you are trying to compile with this code, compilation will fail. It is same for throwing exception.

This is because after return or throwing exception statement the control will goes to the caller place. So those lines cannot be executed.

In your case you must return some Boolean values.

Code should be like this,

```
public static boolean debug(int a, int b) {
    boolean flag = false;
    if(a+b == 12) {
       flag = true;
    }else if(a+b == 18){
        flag = false;
    }
    a = 8;
    return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any code after a return. The warning is saying you're *missing a return*

Note: It's not recommended to alter your parameters `a = 8;`, but if neither your if statements are entered, you must return *something*. In this case true or false after that line

You might also want to capture the result of `debug(4, 5);`

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is trying to tell you (in its own way) that the `else` case (`a+b != 12 && a+b != 18`) is falling through to the `a=8` line and that branch of code is missing a `return` statement.

Java compiler is extremely smart with program flow analysis, so when it tells something is wrong then something is indeed wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Every possible execution path should end with a `return` statement.

In this case, not all your paths return a value. If a+b is neither 12 nor 18, it'll fall through to the line `a=8`. That is not followed by a `return` statement, it just falls through to the end of the method. The compiler doesn't know what it should return in this case, so it issues an error.

Answer (score 1):

Think what happens if you call debug(0, 0). Neither of the if statements are executed so the debug method is not returning nothing.

You must return some boolean value in each possible ramification.

Answer (score 1):

What will return if the both the if the condition fails?. The code is not returning anything if both if the condition fails. So you should return something for that. You must return value for every condition possible.

Answer (score 0):

Return will be the last statement of your method if you want to return any value. Your method need to return some value here.
Lets take a scenario : What if both your if else condition is wrong then what will your method return.

Comment: You can also write return statement after you wrote a=8; but then your if condition will not make any sense.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: It does answer the question IMO; but it's an oversimplification. The last statement in every execution path should be a `return` statement; not just the last statement of the method.

Answer (score -2):

you can write a =8; inside else block.

Comment: this would not solve the issue. returning a boolean value in the "else" block  would

Comment: check this out.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628784/in-java-i-cant-add-code-after-the-return-statement-in-a-method#comment92352168_52628784